# Zoom in on a web page using WebBrowser .NET control

Tags: .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

In IE7 there's a "zoom" feature built-in (show in the status bar), allowing you to zoom in up to 400%. I'm using the WebBrowser .NET control in a demo/simulation app, and need to zoom in on a web page. Is this at all possible?

(I don't want to simply take a picture of the page and enlarge it, as I need to use the links and buttons on the page).

I'm using .NET 2.0 if it matters.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There appears to be a solution at [**IE Zoom**](http://slingkid.blogsome.com/2007/04/13/ie-zoom/) that involves overriding `AttachInterfaces` and `DetachInterfaces` in the `WebBrowser` to get a `IWebBrowser2` interface, and then calling `ExecWB` with `OLECMDID_OPTICAL_ZOOM`.

I've tried his [sample code](http://teleios.bz/download/ZoomBrowser.zip) and it appears to work; the (abridged) relevant class looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ZoomBrowser
{
    public partial class MyBrowser : WebBrowser
    {
        #region enums
        public enum OLECMDID
        {
            // ...
            OLECMDID_OPTICAL_ZOOM = 63,
            OLECMDID_OPTICAL_GETZOOMRANGE = 64,
            // ...
        }

        public enum OLECMDEXECOPT
        {
            // ...
            OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER,
            // ...
        }

        public enum OLECMDF
        {
            // ...
            OLECMDF_SUPPORTED = 1
        }
        #endregion

        #region IWebBrowser2
        [ComImport, /*SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity,*/
         TypeLibType(TypeLibTypeFlags.FOleAutomation | 
                     TypeLibTypeFlags.FDual |       
                     TypeLibTypeFlags.FHidden), 
         Guid("D30C1661-CDAF-11d0-8A3E-00C04FC9E26E")]
        public interface IWebBrowser2
        {
            [DispId(100)]  void GoBack();
            [DispId(0x65)] void GoForward();
            [DispId(0x66)] void GoHome();
            [DispId(0x67)] void GoSearch();
            [DispId(0x68)] void Navigate([In] string Url, 
                                         [In] ref object flags, 
                                         [In] ref object targetFrameName, 
                                         [In] ref object postData, 
                                         [In] ref object headers);
            [DispId(-550)] void Refresh();
            [DispId(0x69)] void Refresh2([In] ref object level);
            [DispId(0x6a)] void Stop();
            [DispId(200)]  object Application 
                           { [return: 
                              MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IDispatch)] get; }
            [DispId(0xc9)] object Parent 
                           { [return: 
                              MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IDispatch)] get; }
            [DispId(0xca)] object Container 
                           { [return: 
                              MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IDispatch)] get; }
            [DispId(0xcb)] object Document 
                           { [return: 
                              MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IDispatch)] get; }
            [DispId(0xcc)] bool TopLevelContainer { get; }
            [DispId(0xcd)] string Type { get; }
            [DispId(0xce)] int Left { get; set; }
            [DispId(0xcf)] int Top { get; set; }
            [DispId(0xd0)] int Width { get; set; }
            [DispId(0xd1)] int Height { get; set; }
            [DispId(210)]  string LocationName { get; }
            [DispId(0xd3)] string LocationURL { get; }
            [DispId(0xd4)] bool Busy { get; }
            [DispId(300)]  void Quit();
            [DispId(0x12d)] void ClientToWindow(out int pcx, out int pcy);
            [DispId(0x12e)] void PutProperty([In] string property, 
                                             [In] object vtValue);
            [DispId(0x12f)] object GetProperty([In] string property);
            [DispId(0)] string Name { get; }
            [DispId(-515)] int HWND { get; }
            [DispId(400)] string FullName { get; }
            [DispId(0x191)] string Path { get; }
            [DispId(0x192)] bool Visible { get; set; }
            [DispId(0x193)] bool StatusBar { get; set; }
            [DispId(0x194)] string StatusText { get; set; }
            [DispId(0x195)] int ToolBar { get; set; }
            [DispId(0x196)] bool MenuBar { get; set; }
            [DispId(0x197)] bool FullScreen { get; set; }
            [DispId(500)] void Navigate2([In] ref object URL, 
                                         [In] ref object flags, 
                                         [In] ref object targetFrameName, 
                                         [In] ref object postData, 
                                         [In] ref object headers);
            [DispId(0x1f5)] OLECMDF QueryStatusWB([In] OLECMDID cmdID);
            [DispId(0x1f6)] void ExecWB([In] OLECMDID cmdID, 
                                        [In] OLECMDEXECOPT cmdexecopt, 
                                        ref object pvaIn, IntPtr pvaOut);
            [DispId(0x1f7)] void ShowBrowserBar([In] ref object pvaClsid, 
                                                [In] ref object pvarShow, 
                                                [In] ref object pvarSize);
            [DispId(-525)] WebBrowserReadyState ReadyState { get; }
            [DispId(550)] bool Offline { get; set; }
            [DispId(0x227)] bool Silent { get; set; }
            [DispId(0x228)] bool RegisterAsBrowser { get; set; }
            [DispId(0x229)] bool RegisterAsDropTarget { get; set; }
            [DispId(0x22a)] bool TheaterMode { get; set; }
            [DispId(0x22b)] bool AddressBar { get; set; }
            [DispId(0x22c)] bool Resizable { get; set; }
        }
        #endregion

        private IWebBrowser2 axIWebBrowser2;

        public MyBrowser()
        {           
        }

        protected override void AttachInterfaces(
            object nativeActiveXObject)
        {
            base.AttachInterfaces(nativeActiveXObject);
            this.axIWebBrowser2 = (IWebBrowser2)nativeActiveXObject;
        }

        protected override void DetachInterfaces()
        {
            base.DetachInterfaces();
            this.axIWebBrowser2 = null;
        }

        public void Zoom(int factor)
        {
            object pvaIn = factor;
            try
            {
                this.axIWebBrowser2.ExecWB(OLECMDID.OLECMDID_OPTICAL_ZOOM,
                   OLECMDEXECOPT.OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER, 
                   ref pvaIn, IntPtr.Zero);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any way so that the horizontal scroll bars does not come, and the text flow to the next line.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It seems that setting is only allowed if the browser is not currently loading a document, so remember to check the `IsBusy` property before setting the zoom factor.

Comment: If you keep getting _DRAGDROP_E_NOTREGISTERED_ error and don't know why make sure IE zoom is not disabled in registry. Check if you have _ZoomDisabled=1_ value under _HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Zoom_ and if yes remove it. Might save you some time.

Comment: link to original article: http://web.archive.org/web/20111228094455/http://slingkid.blogsome.com/2007/04/13/ie-zoom

Comment: Is there a way to get the zoom factor instead of setting it?

Answer (score 18):

Easy tip:

```
//Zoom IN
webBrowser1.Focus();
SendKeys.Send("^{+}"); // [CTRL]+[+]

//Zoom OUT
webBrowser1.Focus();
SendKeys.Send("^-"); // [CTRL]+[-]

//Zoom 100%
webBrowser1.Focus();
SendKeys.Send("^0"); // [CTRL]+[0]
```

Comment: This give me an error in WPF/WinForms SendKeys cannot run inside this application because the application is not handling Windows messages.

Answer (score 14):

This works for me:

```
int zoomFactor = 300;
((SHDocVw.WebBrowser)webBrowser1.ActiveXInstance).ExecWB(SHDocVw.OLECMDID.OLECMDID_OPTICAL_ZOOM,
    SHDocVw.OLECMDEXECOPT.OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER, zoomFactor, IntPtr.Zero);
```

It seems this can be done only after the document has been loaded.

Comment: Need to add a COM reference to C:\Windows\System32\shdocvw.dll also.

Comment: Rather, add a reference to "Microsoft Internet Controls".

Comment: I get an error when I try this. Trying to revoke a drop target that has not been registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040100 (DRAGDROP_E_NOTREGISTERED))

Comment: I got DRAGDROP_E_NOTREGISTERED when trying to apply the zoom immediately after setting a document. It works well if called in an event handler for DocumentCompleted (WinForms)

Answer (score 11):

You can use CSS:

```
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.Document.Body.Style = "zoom:50%";
    }
```

Comment: This was the easiest solution. Very nice. Just add the event handler to the DocumentCompleted event and add the style. Works like a charm. Thank you QHNPROF

Comment: Won't this overwrite any existing style?

Comment: Also, `WebBrowser.Document` is an `object`. How are you accessing `Body`?

Answer (score 2):

Note that the factor value that you pass in to the Zoom function assumes that a value of 100 corresponds to the "normal" size of the web page. Higher values of the factor means you're "zooming in", so the page looks larger. Smaller values of the factor means you're "zooming out", so the page looks smaller.
I found that a reasonable increment between factors is 10.

Answer (score 1):

For anybody that runs into the same issue as I did, here is a modification to Gloupi's answer that should work on more international systems where the plus and minus keys are in different locations by using the numpad sign keys. This also fixes the zoom in and out on dvorak layouts.

```
// zoom in
webBrowser1.Focus();
SendKeys.Send("^{ADD}");

// zoom out
webBrowser1.Focus();
SendKeys.Send("^{SUBTRACT}");

// zoom reset
webBrowser1.Focus();
SendKeys.Send("^0");
```

Comment: `webBrowser1` does not contain a definition for `focus`. So this answer is wrong.

Comment: You should instead use `webBrowser1.Select()`

Comment: @Mark The code is copy pasted from a production application. Probably a version issue I guess?

Comment: Yeah I think so - it would appear `Focus()` was deprecated in favor of `Select()` for certain controls. Not too sure at what .NET version this occurred, but none-the-less :D

Comment: The question does specify .NET 2.0 to be fair, which I'm pretty sure this is correct for. I only posted this answer to point out the use of `^{ADD}` and `^{SUBTRACT}` instead of `^{+}` and `^-` in the otherwise identical answer above by Gloupi, as the latter fails on some non-English and non-QWERTY keyboard layouts.

Comment: You are correct. I must have skipped passed the .NET 2.0. Please ignore my stupidity.