# Not getting how to use the execWB method

Tags: c#

I am unable to get execWB working. Can any one show me how to initialize it or which namespace or dll file I need to include in order to use this method. 
I am trying to zoom out the content on my browser.

Answer (score 0):

You are in luck.  Someone already [wrote the interop](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Interfaces/IWebBrowser2.html) for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at this Stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/738232/zoom-in-on-a-web-page-using-webbrowser-net-control). This CodeProject [link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/webbrowserzoom.aspx) concerns VB.Net but you might be able to get some useful information from it.