# saving google map to image from a browser component window inside a c# application

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, webbrowser-control, screenshot

I wanted to save the google map into an image from a webpage.
while i was searching for that i got this program.
http://www.codres.de/downloads/gms.exe[^]

besides other alternatives like print screen i wanted to use a program or map api which can save a specified dimension of google map instead of the screen.

i have used browser component in c# for http access and for displaying certain webpages.

I want to know whether there are options to capture the browser screen to image using any c# functionality or even the browser component would have given such options. just a guess.

i would like to have answers, suggestions on how to capture the map with custom dimension and zoom size to an image.

Comment: Note that Google Maps has a Static Image API, which generates the map image for you directly: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#quick_example

Comment: Why not to use Static Maps ?https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/

Comment: @user1113426 the static map api gives only 640x480 and not more than that. so i thought of creating an application. besides i have been searching for pixel to latlng with respect to zoom value... if that works then i have another way like taking few 640x480 around a center point and from the output images i will append them to form a very big picture.

Comment: @Piskvor as i have stated in the above comment ... the limitation is 640x480 and i thought of purchasing more but that was a very tedious process so that of doing a gimmick.

Answer (score 0):

I used this to get captcha Image from the current page, so you can use similar code just amend the imageID to point to the google map image and use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/738232/zoom-in-on-a-web-page-using-webbrowser-net-control) for zooming.

```
public string newsavefunction(WebBrowser webBrowser1)
    {
        IHTMLDocument2 doc = (IHTMLDocument2)webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument;
        IHTMLControlRange imgRange = (IHTMLControlRange)((HTMLBody)doc.body).createControlRange();
        string imagename = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            foreach (IHTMLImgElement img in doc.images)
            {
                imgRange.add((IHTMLControlElement)img);

                imgRange.execCommand("Copy", false, null);

                using (Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)Clipboard.GetDataObject().GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap))
                {
                    bmp.Save(@"F:\captchaimages\captchapic.jpg");
                }
                imagename = img.nameProp;
                break;

            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception exp)
        { }
        return imagename;
    }
```