# Web Browser Control - Shrink HTML content

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I have a webpage that loads, and it is way too large. I want to shrink the content that is loaded. How can I accomplish this? A google search only really displays how to increase the size of the browser control to fit the page. I'd like to do the opposite.

Comment: `webBrowser1.Document.Body.Style = "zoom: 50%"` ?

Comment: You may want to look for WebBrowser control **zoom** functionality. Here's a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/738232/161052

Comment: You know like when you have Internet Explorer open and you scroll downward, and the content shrinks? That's what I am looking to do.

Comment: @Sugitime You mean scroll down with mousewheel while holding the control key?

Comment: @JYelton posted a comment that should accomplish this. You basically fire off ExecWB with OLECMDID_OPTICAL_ZOOM.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Someone should post one of these as an 'answer' so I can mark it as the answer to the question.

Comment: Also, does anyone have any code examples of the implementation of JYelton's answer?

Comment: Are you talking about reducing the visible size of the web browser control itself or simply shrinking what it renders? The zoom method is preferable, however you can inject CSS as well as a last resort.