# WPF WebBrowser scaling

Tags: c#, wpf, internet-explorer, com

I've tried some pattern of WPF WebBrowser zoom settings.

1. document.body.runtimeStyle.Zoom = $"{zoomPercent}%"; and doc.parentWindow.execScript($"document.body.style.zoom = {zoomPercent}%;");
2. browser.ExecWB(OLECMDID.OLECMDID_OPTICAL_ZOOM, OLECMDEXEOPT.OLECMDEXEOPT_DODEFAULT, ref zoomPercent);
3. "Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION" value set old compatible setting and newer edge setting. and try 1 and 2.

Text size is applied zoomPercent size. But, Picture and other objects (ex: Images, Background pictures and embedded Flash Player object) are not applied zoomPercent size.

What do I can get really IE like rendering result.

Comment: have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/738232/zoom-in-on-a-web-page-using-webbrowser-net-control

Comment: already tried. that entry as same as tried scenario 2.