# C# Windows.Forms.WebBrowser scaling

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I have a WebBrowser control in my Windows Forms app and want to change the "zoom level" of the HTML page I am loading (in my case Bing map).

I expected to find ways to do this at the 'Document' property level, but there is no zoom or height/width/size property to play with (there is at the browser level but I don't want to resize the control itself).

Attached are pics of what I want to do.  Any thoughts?  Thanks.

[Browser zooming issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CApo8.jpg)

Comment: .Document.Body.Style= "zoom:[Zoom Factor]"; => ie. `webBrowser1.Document.Body.Style= "zoom:75%";` Long answer [Zoom in on a web page using WebBrowser .NET control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/738232/zoom-in-on-a-web-page-using-webbrowser-net-control).

Comment: Thks Jimi, unfortunately this solution doesn't work.  If you specify a zoom level of 50%, the document shrinks by half but only half of the web control is used to render the page.  I want the page to shrink, but not the usable area of the web control ....

Comment: I know, that's the trivial method. The "Long answer" would be the good one. But you could also use the SHDocVw Interface, which needs a reference to "Microsoft Internet Controls" type library (might have side-effects). If you decide to try it, cast the Activex Instance of your WebBrowser to the SHDocVw Interface: `SHDocVw.WebBrowser _Wb = (SHDocVw.WebBrowser)webBrowser1.ActiveXInstance;`  Execute the Zoom command: `_Wb.ExecWB(OLECMDID.OLECMDID_OPTICAL_ZOOM, OLECMDEXECOPT.OLECMDEXECOPT_PROMPTUSER, (object)Zoom_Factor, Type.Missing);` Zoom_Factor is the usual value with 100=normal view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jimi is basically right. But I will go ahead and give you the full code/explanation.

You want to add a COM reference to Microsoft Internet Controls so you have access to ShDocVw.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace winforms
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            webBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri("http://www.google.com"));
            webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted;
        }

        private void WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            var browser = webBrowser1.ActiveXInstance as SHDocVw.InternetExplorer;
            browser.ExecWB(SHDocVw.OLECMDID.OLECMDID_OPTICAL_ZOOM, SHDocVw.OLECMDEXECOPT.OLECMDEXECOPT_DODEFAULT,200 ,IntPtr.Zero );
        }
    }
}
```

The 200 represents the zoom level.EG 200% zoom. If you did 50% zoom, that would be zooming out.In other words values less than 100 mean zooming out, and values greater than 100 are zooming in. Possible Values range from 10-1000.

**Documnetation Links**

- [OLECMDID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms691264(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [OLECMDEXECOPT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683930(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [ShDcVw.InternetExplorer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752084(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [ExecWB method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752087(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [IE Architecture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa741311(v=vs.85).aspx), [IE Architecture 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa741312(v=vs.85))
- [IE Hosting and Re-Use](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752038(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [Interop with Unmanaged Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/)
- [COM Interop Architecture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb610378.aspx)
- [Introduction to COM Interop (VB)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/com-interop/introduction-to-com-interop)
- [Importing Type Libraries as Assemblies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/importing-a-type-library-as-an-assembly)
- [COM To .Net Datatypes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sak564ww(v=vs.100).aspx)

Unfortunately, many of the COM components are documented for C++ developers not C# as COM is a C++ paradigm around binary compatibility. And thus in C# we can interop with these COM objects that were originally written in C++.

The other trick you have to remember about COM is that each time new functionality is added, it gets added to a new interface. E.G. [IHTMLDocument2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752574(v=vs.85).aspx)  [IHTMLDocument3](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752541(v=vs.85).aspx), [IHTMLDocument4](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752529(v=vs.85).aspx), etc. So you need to know which interface you actually want to cast your COM object to.

Comment: Sure, I updated my answer with some documentation. I probably went a bit overboard, but hopefully it covers the all the baseline subjects that you and other people who see this page will want to ask questions about.