# Scaling a WebBrowswer containing an .xps document

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to display an .xps document to a separate window.  I put it in a WebBrowser, I get the document I'm after.

Unfortunately, the target platform is a huge 4k monitor meant to be seen from some distance away--and it shows up unacceptably small.  I'm getting nowhere on trying to scale the display up--the browser ignores things like Scale(new SizeF(2f, 2f);

So far the only answer we have found is the ugly one of setting the monitor at 1080p rather than 4k.  Simply switching the fonts has not been tried and is not an answer anyway as the machine also has an ordinary monitor that will be seen at ordinary distance.

The material being displayed is always just one page that was just extracted from a larger document.  The objective is for this to be visible as the operator walks away from his computer gathering the parts that the document directs.

Comment: Are you asking how to zoom the content view of your webbrowser control or how to build a DPIAware appication?

Comment: @Jimi Zoom the view.  DPI awareness would be overkill, I would be happy with a scaling factor in the configuration of the offending station.

Comment: This argument has been tackled a few days ago [Windows.Forms.WebBrowser scaling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48047110/c-sharp-windows-forms-webbrowser-scaling#comment83083009_48047110). If you need some more details, ring back.

Comment: @Jimi That did it.  I found a lot of answers that didn't work before posting this, I didn't find that one.

Comment: Well, good for you. The only thing that is missing is the calculation of the scaling factor that can be translated to the desired zooming factor of the WebBrowser control viewport. This can be easily obtained using the software design machine screen size as the base dimension and establishing a relation with the size of the PrimaryMonitor of the machines where your software is deployed.

Comment: @Jimi I didn't even worry about calculating it.  It's now a config option, the guy on-site (two states away--I'm a remote worker) can figure out the largest value that never causes it to exceed the screen.