# WPF web browser - Zoom function when displaying PDF with the Acrobat control

Tags: c#, wpf, pdf, acrobat

I'll show content in two separate web browser windows in a WPF application. Typically, this content is PDF or XPS files represented by the Adobe Control or XPS viewer. Image files (eg JPG, PNG etc.) as well as HTML content are displayed natively in the web browser.

Everything works well, but I can not adjust the displayed content to the window width or height when I display a PDF file in Acrobat control. I can adjust the content to the desired size (zooming) with the mouse (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+mouse wheel) or with the keyboard (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>), but how do I do that in the program code?

I've tried it with ExecWB: It works for other formats (htmp, jpg, png, xps etc) but it crashes when a PDF file is displayed in the Acrobat control. Here's my code:

```
public static partial class WebBrowserExtensions
{
    public static int Zoom = 100;

    public static void SetZoom(this WebBrowser wb, int _Zoom, string DocumentType, string Source)
    {
        if ((Zoom += _Zoom) < 20)
        {
            Zoom = 20;
        }
        else if (Zoom > 400)
        {
            Zoom = 400;
        }

        if (DocumentType == "PDF")
        {
            wb.Source = new Uri("about:blank");
            wb.Source = new Uri($"{Source}#zoom={Zoom}");
            wb.Refresh();
        }
        else
        {
            object zoom = Zoom;

            var OLECMDEXECOPT_DODEFAULT = 0;
            var OLECMDID_OPTICAL_ZOOM   = 63;

            FieldInfo   fiComWebBrowser     = null;
            object      objComWebBrowser    = null;

            if ((fiComWebBrowser    = typeof(WebBrowser).GetField("_axIWebBrowser2", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic))   != null && 
                (objComWebBrowser   = fiComWebBrowser.GetValue(wb))                                                                     != null)
            {
                objComWebBrowser.GetType().InvokeMember("ExecWB", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, objComWebBrowser, new object[] { OLECMDID_OPTICAL_ZOOM, OLECMDEXECOPT_DODEFAULT, zoom, IntPtr.Zero });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now I try in the "PDF branch" with the parameter "#zoom=factor" to reload the PDF file, but the web browser then shows only a gray window. But if I do this parameter the first time I load the PDF file, it works.

If I could reload and render the PDF file with the "#zoom=factor" parameter, I'll be finished, even if it's not a nice solution.

I also tried `mshtml.IHTMLDocument2`:

```
public static class Extensionmethod
{
    public static void SetZoom(this System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser WebBrowser1, double Zoom)
    {
        // For this code to work: add the Microsoft.mshtml .NET reference      
        mshtml.IHTMLDocument2 doc = WebBrowser1.Document as mshtml.IHTMLDocument2;
        doc.parentWindow.execScript("document.body.style.zoom=" + Zoom.ToString().Replace(",", ".") + ";");
    }
}
```

The result is not really good: The page is zoomed and not the content. This also means that when you zoom out, the parts that were previously out of the visible area are still not displayed, but only a white area.

How do I make Acrobat control to properly zoom in on content in a web browser control?

Comment: Have a look at this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/738232/zoom-in-on-a-web-page-using-webbrowser-net-control For Acrobat control you'll probably need to send an additional zoom command

Comment: Thanks, but that's for Windows Forms. I use WPF though. In WPF, the class WebBrowser is sealed, so I can not derive any new class from it.

I've already implemented the method shown in your example (`public void Zoom(int factor)`) as an extension method (see my code, even if it looks a bit different).

As I wrote, everything works except the Acrobat control.